# How to reply to comments in Android Market?

Tags: android, comments, google-play

As a developer, sometimes we get comments about our apps in the Android market. I hate being unable to find a way to respond back to my customers. Is there a way to reply back to the comments in the Android market?

If yes, Google should really make more obvious to us developers!

Comment: The accepted answer is a little outdated. Check the answer from BluJ IT

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like Google has now given the ability for some developers to begin adding responses to comments within Google Play.  Unfortunately, it is only to Google's "Top Developers"; hopefully, the ability will be extended to all developers soon.  Read more [here](http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/21/google-plays-top-android-devs-can-now-respond-to-user-reviews-snarky-comments/).

Here is the original [Google link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/06/replying-to-user-reviews-on-google-play.html).

Comment: It may be a coincidence, but as of today I'm able to reply to rating comments for my app that just hit 25,000 downloads. According to Google, only "selected" developers are able to do so, but Google will hardly select them manually. 25,000 may be the limit, now I'm waiting for others to confirm...

Comment: It appears to be coincidence as I have a dozen apps on the market and more than 25,000 downloads for more than one app, and I cannot seem to reply to any comments for any app.

Comment: I've seen one developer with one app, almost no downloads, being able to reply. Im not sure how Google select these users? Define top developer?

Answer (score 6):

<strike>**No**</strike>

**Update:**
Yes, please check Jon's and other's answer.
Below is the outdated answer but you can still use some of the ideas.

There is no such function, an alternative way to do that would be adding a feedback function directly in the app and send the message via email or HTTP post back to the developer.

While implementing the feedback system, consider a thread-like conversation with a user if your project is big enough.
You can even use a webview to avoid extra coding in the app and set the webview to a comment page.

Comment: I do have a 'ContactUs' function which allows the user to send me an email directly from the app. But some users still prefer to complain on the Android Market and then I have NO way to reply back to them. Google really should do something about this!!! :/

Comment: i initially feel it the same way, but after a while, you'll see that not every  comment makes sense, for example: "not working, uninstalling" these kind of comment doesn't tell you what's wrong. what google did to prevent this was adding a vote and "mark as spam" function in the android market

Comment: So do the 'Spam' comment not show up in the market? Are they still taken in to consideration while calculating the 'stars'?

Comment: the spam comments gets removed if many uses votes it spam, but i'm  sure with the rating, i believe it goes away too, not too sure

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will accept your explanations for now..I really hope that Google can resolve this sooner than later & help us developers in the long run!

Comment: actually this is no longer correct . developers can reply to users' comments . see this article : http://www.droid-life.com/2013/01/09/google-adds-ability-for-all-developers-to-reply-to-comments-in-play-store/

Comment: Reply is only possible for comments? Can we also reply on ratings? at least we can ask why it is 1 star if somebody gives one star? does anybody know if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is in the pipeline, being deployed to some developers as of the time of posting:  [Google Play will allow Android Developers to reply to customer feedback](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/06/21/like-a-boss-google-play-store-now-allows-developers-to-reply-to-reviews-2/).

Edit 16 Apr 2013:  I can now reply to comments on my own app, as of several weeks ago.  So either the rollout has continued steadily and recently touched me, or it's now available to everyone.

Comment: Some apps in the playstore already contain answers on comments. Currently I am not able to answer comments for my own app. I think the roll out is not finished yet.

Comment: I can't answer on mine yet, either.  As far as I can tell, it's only been rolled out to "top developers" so far.

Comment: Yes, I read about it. Does someone know if there is a timeline for the rollout for all developers?

Comment: It's not true I have seen apps that are being able to reply to Comments  without being Top Developer. This app had almost no downloads. This is not what I like about Google, no transparency  and your out of luck if you need help.

Comment: As of several weeks ago I am able to reply to comments on my own app.  I am not a top developer.

Answer (score 2):

this is no longer impossible .

according to many articles, google has allowed ALL developers to reply to users' comments (ratings) .

example :

http://www.droid-life.com/2013/01/09/google-adds-ability-for-all-developers-to-reply-to-comments-in-play-store/

however , i've checked it today , and i can't find out how to do it . i've searched on both the play store website and the developer console website .

can anyone find how to reply to users' comments ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reply direct on Google Play Console, GPC API or AppFollow.io API.

Example how to reply on reviews in Google Play: https://appfollow.io/blog/how-and-why-to-reply-to-reviews-in-app-store-an-google-play